# A card is lost from the deck of 52 cards. Two cards are drawn and found to be of spades.

Tags: probability, combinations

What is the probability that the lost card was of spades?

My work :

Prob of spades = 13/52

Prob of lost card being spade = 1/13

How do I proceed after this? Is it like P(A/B) = P(A) / P(A $\cap$ B)? I am not able to follow after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $A$ be the event that lost card was spade

Let $B$ be the event that two cards are drawn and found to be spade

You want to compute $P(A|B)$, use Bayes Theorem,

$$P(A|B)=P(B|A)\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Note that you can compute $P(B)$ by

$$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c).$$

Comment: In the question its not clear whether the cards drawn are returned to the deck. Otherwise P(B) will be 2/13 and P(A) =1/13. How do I go about finding P(B A)?

Comment: hmm... if the question is not clear, you will have to ask the person who set the question. Why is it that $P(A)=\frac{1}{13}$?

Comment: There are 13 spades in a deck. 1 card being spade is 1/13 and that is the lost card's probability.

Comment: If you have 13 spades in a complete deck of 52 cards and if you draw a card randomly, what is the probability that you will get a spade?

Comment: It will be 13/52 = 1/4.

Comment: If you have 13 spades in a complete deck of 52 cards and if you draw a card randomly and then throw it away, what is the probability that you will throw away a spade?

Comment: 1 -12/51 = 39/51, I think. I am stuck here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45082/discussion-between-siongthyegoh-and-piepi).

Answer (score 1):

You have got a good answer in a "standard" way, but probability problems can often be very easily solved using a bit of imagination.

You **know** that the two cards drawn are spades,
so (including the lost card), there are $11$ spades in $50$ cards

Thus, very simply, P(lost card is a spade) $= \dfrac{11}{50}$